# Problems with torrent names with brackets in their name

Tags: bash, rtorrent

So when some torrent got downloaded then i execute one script.
Like this `system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,create_torrent,"execute=~/s.sh,$d.get_name="`
The problem with this is - like the name of the question sais - that when the name contains brackets, it doesn't get executed at all and exits with syntax error.
Can someone point me in the right direction, because i have tried a variety of solutions like putting execute into quotes etc. Nothing changed the thing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
The problem was not with rtorrent.rc it was some other script interferring.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your shell is interpriting the brackets inside your torrent names as part of the command, and is trying to figure out what to do with them, causing the errors.

Off the top of my head, but give this a try:

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,create_torrent,"execute=~/s.sh,'$d.get_name='"
```

Comment: `---
^@~/s.sh '$d.get_name='
---
^@ls: cannot access ./downloads/'$d.get_name='/: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory './downloads/u/\'$d.get_name=\'': File exists`
not really working

Comment: how 'bout this?    system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,create_torrent,'execute=~/s.sh,"$d.get_name="'

Comment: like that it is not even starting `rtorrent: Error in option file: ~/.rtorrent.rc:35: Junk at end of input.`
the line 35 is the line with that what you wrote, i tried these variations too with no success at all